# How to get posts from multiple custom post types based on many taxonomy terms

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I want to be able to get posts from different `custom post types` based on multiple `taxonomy terms`.

For example i have a post type called `cme-education` `media gallery` and `post` and I wish to get posts returned from them that matches the taxonomy terms called `covid-19` and `stroke`.

I tried the below code to get the posts individually for each custom post type and then merge those which I can then then use in a wp_query to return the results.

```
$currentID  = get_the_ID();
$test_type = get_test_type($post);
$post_terms = get_terms(array("covid-19", "stroke"));
$postTerm = []; 

foreach ($post_terms as $post_term) {
      $postTerm[] = $post_term->slug; 
} ?>

<?php if (!empty($postTerm)) { ?>

<div class="recommended-activities-section template-in-conversation">
        <?php 
        $first_post_ids = get_posts( array(
            'fields'         => 'ids', // only return post ID´s
            'posts_per_page' => '1',
            'orderby'           =>'rand',
            'post_type'      => 'post',
            'tax_query'         => array (
                array (
                    'taxonomy'  => 'vocabulary_1',
                    'field'     => 'slug',
                    'terms'     => $postTerm,
                    'operator'  => 'IN',
                    'order'     => 'ASC'
                )
            )
        ));

        $second_post_ids = get_posts( array(
            'fields'         => 'ids', // only return post ID´s
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',
            'orderby'           =>'rand',
            'post_type'      => 'cme-education',
            'tax_query'         => array (
                array (
                    'taxonomy'  => 'vocabulary_1',
                    'field'     => 'slug',
                    'terms'     => $postTerm,
                    'operator'  => 'IN',
                    'order'     => 'ASC'
                )
            )
        ));

        $third_post_ids = get_posts( array(
            'fields'         => 'ids', // only return post ID´s
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',
            'orderby'           =>'rand',
            'post_type'      => array('media_gallery'),
            'tax_query'         => array (
                array (
                    'taxonomy'  => 'vocabulary_1',
                    'field'     => 'slug',
                    'terms'     => $postTerm,
                    'operator'  => 'IN',
                    'order'     => 'ASC'
                )
            )
        ));

        $merged_post_ids = array_merge( $first_post_ids, $second_post_ids, $third_post_ids);

        $wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'any', // any post type
            'post__in'  => $merged_post_ids, // our merged queries
            'posts_per_page' => '3',
            'orderby' =>'rand',
        ) ); ?>

        <div class="activity-container">
            <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : 
                while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="recommended-activities-wrap js-recommended-activity-slide">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail("in-convo"); ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="vertical-2-col-split">
                            <div class="recommended-content-top">
                                <h3 class="activity-type">
                                    <?php $general = get_field('general');
                                    $activity_type = $general['activity_type'];
                                    $cme = $general['cme_accredited'];

                                    if( $activity_type ) { ?>
                                    <?php echo $activity_type;?>
                                    <?php } else if ( 'media_gallery' == get_post_type() ) {
                                        echo "CONFERENCE HUB";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "JOURNALS";
                                    } ?>
                                </h3>
                            
                                <h4 class="activity-title dark-blue-text"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>

                                <?php if ( 'cme-education' == get_post_type() ) { ?>
                                <span class="accreditation-type"><i class="fa-thin fa-award"></i>  This activity is CE/CME accredited</span>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                            <a class="c-button mb-0 dark-blue-bg" href="<?php the_permalink() ?> " target="_blank">
                                <?php if ('media_gallery' == get_post_type() ) {
                                    echo "GO TO HUB";
                                } else if ('cme-education' == get_post_type()) {
                                    echo "LAUNCH ACTIVITY";
                                } else {
                                    echo "GO TO ARTICLE";
                                } ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile;

                // reset after query
                wp_reset_query();

                else :
                    echo 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.';
            endif; ?>
        </div>
</div>
<?php } else {
    echo "";
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: it's not reading the terms

Comment: I managed to solve this using a stack overflow answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91084/display-all-posts-for-taxonomy-term-across-multiple-custom-post-types)